# Matrix subtraction in python/numpy

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I have an implementation of kalman filter where I am doing matrix operations. At some point I should subtract two 1x1 matrices. I have an error, which I don't know where it's coming from. 
What is the best way to do matrix operations in python?

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import scipy as Sci
import scipy.linalg as linalg

class GetPos(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Posp = 0
        self.Velp = 80
        self.z = np.matrix(0)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "from GetPos.__repr__ z=%s" % (self.z)
    def __call__(self):
        self.dt = 0.1
        self.w = 0 + 10*np.random.random()
        self.v = 0 + 10*np.random.random()            
        self.z = self.Posp + self.Velp*self.dt + self.v
        self.Posp = self.z - self.v
        self.Velp = 80 + self.w
        print 'from GetPos.__call__ z = %s' % self.z
        return self.z

class DvKalman(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dt = .1
        self.A = np.matrix([[1., self.dt],[0,1]])
        self.H = np.matrix([1., 0])
        self.Q = np.matrix([[1,0.],[0,3]])
        self.R = np.matrix(10)
        self.x = np.matrix([0,20]).T
        self.P = np.matrix(5*np.eye(2))
        #print 'P matrix \n%s' % self.P
        self.firstRun = 0
    def __call__(self, z):
        self.z = z
        print 'from DvKalman.__call__ slef.z = %s and z = %s' % (self.z,z)
        self.xp = self.A * self.x
        self.Pp = self.A*self.P*self.A.T  + self.Q
        self.K = self.Pp * self.H.T * linalg.inv(np.absolute(self.H*self.Pp*self.H.T + self.R));
        print 'from DvKalman.__call__  z=%s, \npreviouse x=\n%s \nH = \n%s \nand P=\n%s \nand xp=\n%s,\n Pp = \n%s,\n K=\n%s' % (self.z,self.x,self.H, self.P,self.xp,self.Pp,self.K)
        newM1 = self.H*self.xp    
        print 'This is self.H*self.xp %s and this is self.z = %s' % (newM1, self.z)
        newM2 = self.z - self.H*self.xp
        print 'This should give simple substruction %s' % newM2                 
        self.x = self.xp + self.K*(self.z - self.H*self.xp)
        self.P = self.Pp - self.K*self.H*self.Pp
        print 'new values x=%s and P=%s' % (self.x,self.P)
        return (self.x)
def TestDvKalman():
    Nsamples = np.arange(0,10,.1)

    kal = DvKalman()
    #print type(kal)
    Xsaved = []
    Zsaved = []

    for i in range(len(Nsamples)):
        z = GetPos()
        print z
        print 'from TestDvKalman zpos = %s' % z
        Zsaved.append(z)
        [position, velocity] = kal(z)
        print position, velocity
        Xsaved.append([position, velocity])
    print Zsaved
    print Xsaved
#    f1 = pl.subplot(121)
#    f1 = pl.plot(Xsaved, 'x-',label = 'Xsaved')
#    f1 = pl.legend()
#    
#    f2 = pl.subplot(122)
#    f2 = pl.title('Kalman Velocity')
#    f2 = pl.plot(Zsaved, 'o-', color = 'brown',label = 'Zsaved')
#    f2 = pl.legend()
#    
#    pl.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    TestDvKalman()
```

I've added a few `print` lines to follow and debug the code and I added new variable `newM` which wouldn't be in the code. The matrices prints correctly `This is self.H*self.xp [[ 2.]] and this is self.z = from GetPos.__repr__ z=[[0]]` Both matrices are 1x1 but I still recieve an error, don't know why. The error is:

```
    newM2 = self.z - self.H*self.xp
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'GetPos' and 'matrix'
```

I suspect I'm messing up with type somewhere but don't know where and how to correct it. Can you point me where is the error and how to build a code like that to avoid similar errors in future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `newM2 = self.z - self.H*self.xp` by `newM2 = self.z() - self.H*self.xp`.

The program should work with that ( but I can't confirm if it gonna do want you want )

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a GetPos instance to DvKalman `__call__` method. So you are trying to substract a GetPos instance and a matrix. Not a matrix and a matrix.

Comment: Thanks. That's correct but how I should do than. Every time I call `DvKalman` I want to have new variable 'z' coming from `GetPos`

Answer (score 2):

In `TestDvKalman`, this line

```
    z = GetPos()
```

sets `z` to an instance of `GetPos`.  You use this as an argument to `kal` in this line:

```
    [position, velocity] = kal(z)
```

so the `__call__` method of `DvKalman` is given an instance of `GetPos`, which you save as `self.z`.  That results in the error at this line:

```
    newM2 = self.z - self.H*self.xp
```

Comment: Thanks. I intend to do something like that but I want `z =[[m]]` where `m` is returned from `GetPos.__call__` I understand that this is how it works. What do I miss?

Comment: GetPos() creates an instance of GetPos.  You then have to *call* the object returned by GetPos().  Whether you do that when you create z, or in the `__call__` method in DvKalman depends on how you want it all to work.